# If statement for two different arrays in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop

I have two arrays, which are arrAlpha[] and arrPT[]. Array arrAlpha contains the Alphabets and array arrPT[] contains some of the plain letters.following is the code that i wrote in bash shell script to compare elements of both arrays and to store the position elements of arrPT[] in arrAlpha[] to array arrT[]. But when i run i feel like something is wrong in if statement to print out the elements in arrT[]. can anyone help me please?

```
     #!/bin/bash

     arrAlpha=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)

     arrPT=(E K N R S W )
     lenPT=${#arrPT}
     declare -A arrT
     q=0
     for((i=0; i<lenPT; i++)) do
         for((j=i; j<26; j++)) do
             if [  ${arrPT[$i]}  =  ${arrAlpha[$j]}  ]; then
                 arrT[$q]=$j % 26;
                 ((++q));
             fi
          done
     done

     echo ${arrAlpha[@]}
     echo ${arrPT[@]}
     echo ${arrT[@]}
```

the expected output is to change elements arrPT to number 0 to 25.

```
    arrAlpha=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
    arrPT =(E K N R S W)
    arrT =(4 10 13 17 18 22)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "feel like something wrong" ? Did the output is not as you expected?

Comment: what i mean by feel like something is, i'm not sure about if statement that i wrote is correct or not. can u help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your script - there are some style changes that I prefer

```
arrAlpha=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
arrPT=(E K N R S W )
# array length needs index *
lenPT=${#arrPT[*]}
# seems arrT can be simple indexed array
declare -a arrT
q=0
for((i=0; i<lenPT; ++i)); do
  for((j=0; j<26; ++j)); do
    if [[ ${arrPT[i]} == ${arrAlpha[j]} ]]; then
# arithmetic inside $(())
      arrT[q++]=$((j % 26))
    fi
  done
done
echo ${arrAlpha[@]}
echo ${arrPT[@]}
echo ${arrT[@]}
```

Comment: FYI, in `[[ $foo == $bar ]]`, `$bar` is treated as a glob expansion unless quoted; if, for instance, it were `*`, it would match anything. If you don't want that behavior, consider quoting the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

The main bug is with this line:

```
lenPT=${#arrPT}
```

which should be written like:

```
lenPT=${#arrPT[@]}
```

But, in fact, there is no need (even if it is not wrong to use it) for such variable, change this line:

```
for((i=0; i<lenPT; i++)) do
```

to:

```
for((i=0; i<${#arrPT[@]}; i++)) do
```

Some other issues:

- There is no need to `mod 26` the value of `$j`, it will never reach 26.
- The array `arrT` seems to be an indexed array: `-a` no need for `-A`.
- There is no need for variable `q` if each result will be in the same position as the index `i`
- Please *quote your expansions*.
- Use printf (more reliable) instead of echo.

The script with all the above done is:

```
#!/bin/bash

 arrAlpha=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
 arrPT=(E K N R S W )

 declare -a arrT

 for((i=0; i<${#arrPT[@]}; i++)) do
    for((j=i; j<${#arrAlpha[@]}; j++)) do
       [[  ${arrPT[i]}  ==  "${arrAlpha[j]}"  ]] && let arrT[i]=j
    done
 done

 printf '%s ' "${arrAlpha[@]}"  ; echo 
 printf '%3s ' "${arrPT[@]}"    ; echo 
 printf '%3s ' "${arrT[@]}" ; echo
```

Of course, the second loop could be removed by cutting that string at the character:

```
#!/bin/bash

Alpha=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
arrPT=(E K N R S W )

declare -a arrT

for((i=0; i<${#arrPT[@]}; i++)) do
    arrT[i]=${Alpha%"${arrPT[i]}"*}    # cut the string at the character.
    arrT[i]=${#arrT[i]}                # Use the len of the cut string.
done

printf '%s ' "$Alpha"           ; echo 
printf '%3s ' "${arrPT[@]}" ; echo 
printf '%3s ' "${arrT[@]}"      ; echo
```